# Creating/Adding user on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I have been playing with Firebase and I got stuck with a question, I tried to look some docs but I couldn't find a proper answer.

The thing is that Firebase provides a user authentication, that's good, but can I set some limits to this user? So it could have access just to one part of my database scheme? e.g: have two grupos on my database:

https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/group1/posts/
https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/group2/posts/

and which one has different users, different posts.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**You're looking for Security Rules.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html)

Security Rules are server side validations that restrict access to your Firebase database.

Below are the rules for a read-only database.

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".false": false
  }
}
```

Security Rules provide server variables that hold important server-side information. [The variable you'll be interested in is the `auth` variable.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-variable)

The auth variable allows you to check if the user trying to access the database is authenticated.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "group1": {
       ".read": "auth !== null",
       ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

According the rules above only authenticated users can access the `/group1` location.

But for user based security, you'll need to index using the user's `uid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "group1": {
       "posts": {
         "$uid": {
           ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
           ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And [using wildcards (which are basically route parameters)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables), you can check to see if the user trying to access the data owns the data.